# How to solve json loading issue?

Tags: json, python-3.x, web-scraping

I just started learning web scraping with Python 3, and I am trying to apply it in a small project which consists of extracting data from job listings. I did look for answers and found some questions which touched a somewhat similar subject, but none of them seemed to have the exact same use case - at least that is my understanding.

I extracted company URLs from the search results of a website and appended the company URLs in a list named *sitelis*. Then, I looped through *sitelis* to extract the json data from each of the company URLs. However, I have a problem to retrieve the json data from some of the company URLs (see traceback: **json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape**) - while the large majority URLs work just fine. Any idea what could cause this? I am a bit lost since 90% of the URLs work fine, and for those few which do not parse correctly I cannot find any differences which would explain it.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Here is an example of such an error:

This is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "glassdoor_json.py", line 117, in <module>
    company_js = json.loads(company_jdata.text, strict=False)    # to get a Python list
  File "/Users/spw/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 361, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
  File "/Users/spw/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Users/spw/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 54 column 92 (char 2146)
```

This is the code for the for-loop:

```
for site in sitelis:
        count_site = count_site + 1
        try:
            companyrstarturl = Request(site, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
            fhand_company = urllib.request.urlopen(companyrstarturl, context=ctx)
            companydata = fhand_company.read()
            company_soup = BeautifulSoup(companydata, 'lxml')
            company_jdata = company_soup.select("[type='application/ld+json']")[0]
            company_js = json.loads(company_jdata.text, strict=False)    # to get a Python list
            print('')
            print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> (json) Company', count_site, '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<' )
            print('')
            print(json.dumps(company_js, indent=4))
            print('')
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('')
            print('(2) Program interrupted by user...')
            break
```

This is the associated json data from a company website (the one with traceback):

```
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "JobPosting",
        "title": "Back-End Developer (m/w/d)",
        "url": "https://www.glassdoor.de/job-listing/back-end-developer-mwd-storming-creative-studios-JV_IC2561561_KO0,22_KE23,48.htm?jl=3655406413",
        "datePosted": "2020-08-25",
        "employmentType": "FULL_TIME",
    
        "salaryCurrency": "EUR",
    
    
        "validThrough": "2020-09-26",
        
        "hiringOrganization": {
            "@type": "Organization",
            "name": "STORMING GmbH Creative Studios"
        },
        "jobLocation": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "address": {
                "@type": "PostalAddress",
                
                "addressLocality": "Leonberg",
                "addressRegion": "01",
                
                "addressCountry": {
                    "@type" : "Country",
                    "name" : "DE"
                }
            }
            
            ,
            "geo": {
                "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
                "latitude": "48.8005",
                "longitude": "9.0168"
            }
            
        }
        
        ,"description": "In den STORMING Creative Studios wird Kommunikation neu gedacht: In f&amp;uuml;nf einzigartigen Studios b&amp;uuml;ndeln wir unsere Kompetenzen und erschaffen innovative Kommunikationsdienstleistungen. Wir blicken auf beeindruckendes Wachstum zur&amp;uuml;ck und schauen in eine ambitionierte Zukunft. Werde jetzt Teil des Teams.
&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
In unserem Development Studio entstehen innovative Webseiten, durchdachte Apps und hilfreiche Software. Dabei bieten wir unseren Kunden immer die neuesten Technologien und zielf&amp;uuml;hrendsten L&amp;ouml;sungen. F&amp;uuml;r unser Team suchen wir daher Back-End Developer f&amp;uuml;r folgende Aufgaben:


&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Arbeit an Unternehmenssoftware zur Digitalisierung von Prozessen&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Anpassungen an CMS-Backends&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Erstellung von Konfiguratoren&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Enge Zusammenarbeit mit Front-End Developern und Projektleitungen&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;

Uns ist wichtig, dass wir uns aufeinander verlassen und uns vertrauen k&amp;ouml;nnen. Jede\*r bei STORMING ist ein wichtiger Teil des Unternehmens, tr&amp;auml;gt Verantwortung und unterst&amp;uuml;tzt aktiv unser Wachstum. Aus diesem Grund suchen wir nach loyalen Mitarbeitern\*innen mit hoher Motivation. Dar&amp;uuml;ber hinaus ist uns folgendes wichtig:


&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Hervorragende Kenntnisse in PHP, Javascript &amp;amp; SQL&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Kenntnisse in Pythan, Objective-C/Swift &amp;amp; Java von Vorteil&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Berufserfahrung&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Zuverl&amp;auml;ssigkeit&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;

F&amp;uuml;r uns sind faire Bezahlung und geldwerte Vorteile eine Selbstverst&amp;auml;ndlichkeit. Doch auch dar&amp;uuml;ber hinaus ist unser Ziel, einen Ort zu schaffen, an dem Menschen sich gern aufhalten und sie selbst sein k&amp;ouml;nnen.Zusammengefasst bieten wir dir:


&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;gute Work-Life-Balance&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;faire Bezahlung &amp;amp; geldwerte Vorteile&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;moderne Ausstattung &amp;amp; firmeneigene Parkpl&amp;auml;tze&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;flache Hierarchien &amp;amp; kurze Entscheidungswege&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;

Interesse? Dann bewirb dich jetzt per Mail mit deinem Lebenslauf und Portfolio. Wir freuen uns auf dich!
&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
Art der Stelle: Vollzeit"
    }
```

And here is an example of a json (from a company website) which worked fine:

```
{
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "JobPosting",
        "title": "Back-End Node Developer",
        "url": "https://www.glassdoor.de/job-listing/back-end-node-developer-ust-global-JV_IC2622109_KO0,23_KE24,34.htm?jl=3615685703",
        "datePosted": "2020-08-28",
        "employmentType": "FULL_TIME",
    
        "salaryCurrency": "EUR",
    
    
        "validThrough": "2020-09-27",
        "industry": "Information Technology",
        "hiringOrganization": {
            "@type": "Organization",
            "name": "UST Global",
            "logo": "https://media.glassdoor.com/sqll/155577/ust-global-squarelogo-1579115891630.png",
            "sameAs": "www.ust-global.com"
            
        },
        "jobLocation": {
            "@type": "Place",
            "address": {
                "@type": "PostalAddress",
                
                "addressLocality": "Berlin",
                "addressRegion": "16",
                
                "addressCountry": {
                    "@type" : "Country",
                    "name" : "DE"
                }
            }
            
            ,
            "geo": {
                "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
                "latitude": "52.5177",
                "longitude": "13.4055"
            }
            
        }
        
            ,"occupationalCategory" : ["15-1132.00", "Software Developers, Applications"]
        
        ,"description": "&lt;p&gt;UST Global is increasing its International Digital &amp;amp; Innovation Hub in Berlin in partnership model with one of our Fortune 500 clients, to deliver new digital solutions in more than 60 countries as part of their business transformation model.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;The Hub team leads the end-to-end process of creating new capabilities, products and platforms, applying best practices, top technology trends and agile techniques.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;As part of our Digital Hub based in Berlin, you will have the opportunity to work in a multicultural and highly dynamic environment. You will have the chance to live the first steps of this international, highly skilled, success-oriented team.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Key responsibilities&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;As part of our digital squads you will work on state-of-the-art technologies to design and create products for creating new business models, that will transform the way of interacting between people and enterprises:&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;E2E responsibility for building digital products and solutions.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Build AI solutions.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Apply architecture principles and development standards.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Work closely with other technical teams undertaking product development coordination and delivery.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Basic qualifications:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;You are experienced in JavaScript/TypeScript&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;You are familiar with building scalable applications and services with Node.js&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;You have knowledge in relational databases like Postgres&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Monitoring with ELK (Elastic Search, LogStash, Kibana)&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Use of best practices in clean code, testing and code review.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Understanding on quality documentation and diagrams.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Experience working with Agile principles and best practices.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Good time management skills.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Real passion of coding and technology&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;A degree in computer science, or similar professional certifications.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Fluent English and excellent communication skills.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Used to work in multinational projects.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Desirable qualifications:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Experience implementing and managing CI/CD solutions.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Experience under some of the following frameworks: Angular or React.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Knowledge of Kafka is a plus&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Suitable candidates:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;German passport holders&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;German valid working visa&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;European Union passport holders&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt; &lt;/strong&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Who we are:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;We are a multinational digital company with over 20.000 employees all over the world and presence in more than 25 countries.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;We transform lives with our human centered innovative solutions, touching 3 billion &amp;ldquo;personas&amp;rdquo; through digital solutions and technologies.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;UST Global is a Great Place to Work&amp;reg; and Top Employer&amp;reg; certified company.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;For further details please go to www.ust-global.com&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;What we offer:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Competitive compensation package and benefits.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Flexible Payment Plan so you can adapt your salary according to your preferences (child care checks, transport card, online German and English lessons with native teachers, health insurance&amp;hellip;).&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;25 working days of holidays.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Free breakfast, food and drinks.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Team activities like barbecues, game nights, team events and much more.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Professional career in our Center of Excellence where you could participate on several projects inside the company.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;International environment and close contact with colleagues specialized in the core technologies of the company, with whom you will share your knowledge.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;We have an (internal) program to compensate referrals from which you can benefit when you refer professionals that get on the company.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;p&gt;If you want to know more, don&amp;rsquo;t hesitate to apply and we&amp;rsquo;ll get in touch with you to give more details about the offer. If you are a digital native, this is an amazing opportunity to join one of the leading initiatives in Central Europe, Berlin.&lt;/p&gt;"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out how to solve the issue.

The issue was caused by escaped backslashes, `\`, on some of the json data. An escape sequence contains two/more characters starting with a backlash, such as '\n' that represents a newline, where '\' does not represent itself. Examples of escaped backlashes on some of the data:

```
&lt;li&gt;Enge Abstimmung mit Designer\*innen &amp;amp; Projektleitung&lt;/li&gt;
```

and

```
Aus diesem Grund suchen wir nach loyalen Mitarbeitern\*innen mit hoher Motivation.
```

Here is the solution:

```
company_js = json.loads(company_jdata.text.replace('\\', '/'), strict=False)
```

In order to solve the problem, `'/'` is used in the second argument as a replacement for the escaped backslash. In the first argument, `'\\'` is used: an additional backlash is used together with the '\'  to escape the escape backlash (i.e. `'\\'` is actually representing `'\'`).

Answer (score 0):

> Uns ist wichtig, dass wir uns aufeinander verlassen und uns vertrauen k&ouml;nnen. Jede*r bei STORMING ist ein wichtiger Teil des Unternehmens, tr&auml;gt Verantwortung und unterst&uuml;tzt aktiv unser Wachstum. Aus diesem Grund suchen wir nach loyalen Mitarbeitern*innen mit hoher Motivation. Dar&uuml;ber hinaus ist uns folgendes wichtig:

That is line 53 in the non functional example you have. I see a non escaped colon at the end of the line, which the JSON parser might treat as a key:pair delimiter. If this is the case, would possibly explain the error and you would need some type of sanitizer to capture and properly escape these.

Not sure if that is something built in, or if you would need to make your own. Maybe someone else can offer a solution to how to handle that.

I also see the same thing on line 63

> F&uuml;r uns sind faire Bezahlung und geldwerte Vorteile eine Selbstverst&auml;ndlichkeit. Doch auch dar&uuml;ber hinaus ist unser Ziel, einen Ort zu schaffen, an dem Menschen sich gern aufhalten und sie selbst sein k&ouml;nnen.Zusammengefasst bieten wir dir: